# Mimicking Latex Style

Tags: margins, geometry, rules, mdframed

I recently stumbled across the mathematics textbook Numerical Analysis 9th edition by Burden and Faires and I thoroughly enjoyed the style of it. I was able to find a link too here: https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/numerical_analysis_9th.pdf. I was wondering if someone could help me with trying to mimic the style.

Since the style of the book seems rather broad, I will start by trying to tackle these parts first:

- Theorems, tables, ect. in the margin notes section and aligning them with content in the body section

  - I have some starter code for this using the marginnote package and using reversemarginpar to get the notes in the left margin but I was curious if someone could do better or improve on this
- Spanning blue bars over each of the section headers that span the left margin notes and body section

  - Unsure of how to do this as current attempts produce lines spanning the body section and right margin notes
- Having graphs and images in centered style formats in the blue frame boxes

  - I am pretty sure that the mdframed package can handle this but I just wanted to see what others may say

If anyone needs any further information or examples from me, I would be happy to provide it. Thank you for your time and help!

Sample code for the margin notes:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\geometry{
a4paper,
left=2in,
right=1in,
marginparwidth=1.75in,
marginparsep=.25in
}
\reversemarginpar

% Setup counters for side margins
\newcounter{TheoremCounter}[section]
\newcounter{DefinitionCounter}[section]
\newcounter{ExampleCounter}[section]
\newcounter{FigureCounter}[section]
\newcounter{TableCounter}[section]

\newcommand{\side}[1]{{\marginnote{
\color[HTML]{156EC7} \large \textbf{ #1 
\thesection.\the\numexpr\value{#1Counter}+1\relax}}} 
\stepcounter{#1Counter}}

\begin{document}
% example how I have used it
\side{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. I see a couple of questions. Try one at a time with the [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557) code that you have tried.

Comment: @nidhin I have added an MWE for the marginnotes section. Hopefully that makes it more clear. Unfortunately I have yet to get the spanning section header working so I am at a loss there.

Comment: It might be a stretch, but have you tried calling the publishers of the book to see if they'd be willing to share their style files with you?